# Verification on showing mappings are linear operators

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification, linear-transformations

I want to show that in general, mappings with the forms below from $C^\infty (R)$ to $ C^\infty (R)$ are either going to be linear operators or not. Satisfying $A(\alpha x + \beta y) = \alpha Ax + \beta Ay$. Is what I did correct?

> (1) $f  \rightarrow a f^" +bf^, +cf+d$ (Not a linear operator)

$A(\alpha f_1 + \beta f_2) = a(\alpha f_1 + \beta f_2)^"+b(\alpha f_1 + \beta f_2)^,+c(\alpha f_1 + \beta f_2)+d $

$=a\alpha f_1 ^" +a \beta f_2^" +b\alpha f_1^, + b\beta f_2^, +c\alpha f_1 + c\beta f_2  +d$

$= \alpha Ax + \beta Ay +d$

> (2) $f  \rightarrow a f^" +bf^, +cf$ (A linear operator)

$A(\alpha f_1 + \beta f_2) = a(\alpha f_1 + \beta f_2)^"+b(\alpha f_1 + \beta f_2)^,+c(\alpha f_1 + \beta f_2) $

$=a\alpha f_1 ^" +a \beta f_2^" +b\alpha f_1^, + b\beta f_2^, +c\alpha f_1 + c\beta f_2  $

$= \alpha Ax + \beta Ay $

> (3) $f  \rightarrow a f^" +bf^, +cf^n$ (Not a linear operator)

$A(\alpha f_1 + \beta f_2) = a(\alpha f_1 + \beta f_2)^"+b(\alpha f_1 + \beta f_2)^,+c(\alpha f_1 + \beta f_2)^n $

$=a\alpha f_1 ^" +a \beta f_2^" +b\alpha f_1^, + b\beta f_2^, +c\alpha^n f_1^n +...+ c\beta^n f_2^n  $

$\neq \alpha Ax + \beta Ay $

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is correct in principle, but if you claim that a map is not linear it is best that you provide an explicit counterexample.

For $(1)$, consider $f \equiv 1$. We have $f \mapsto c + d$ and $2f \mapsto 2c + d \ne 2(c + d)$ as long as $d \ne 0$.

If $d = 0$, then the map is linear.

Similarly, for $(3)$, consider $f \equiv 1$. We have $f \mapsto c$ and $2f \mapsto 2^nc \ne 2c$ as long as $c \ne 0$ and $n \ne 1$.

If $c = 0$ or $n = 1$, then the map is linear.